# Is there a way to determine what RPM --relocate was used to install the rpm package

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

After a rpm package is installed using `--relocate`, is there any way to find out what value was used with the `--relocate` option?

Comment: If you used the terminal and `rpm`, you may be able to use `history | grep "--relocate"`.

Comment: @dotVezz history looks at commands ran by my user. i need to look at the commands ran by the SA.

Comment: @hidralist Could you be more specific about what you mean by "SA"? (Systems Admin?)

Comment: @dotVezz yes, System Admin installed a package, which has `--relocate` option and I don't know what value he/she provided to the `--relocate`. The package has an install script that fails the install if there is no `--relocate` parameter, so I know that he used some value for it.

Comment: Can you simply use `rpm -ql` to see where the files landed?

Comment: @AronGriffis if it was a true relocate i. e. the files would be fiscally relocated, then yes your suggestion would work. Unfortunately this package takes the relocate parameter value and uses it in a post install script to create some links that do not reflect the relocate parameter value. Looking at the post install script code I can only assert what value was NOT used.

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't found a specific command, but I have used this:

rpm -qi |grep Relocations:|awk '{print $5}'